# how to map each column to other column in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created dataframe by executing below code .

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('Ankit',25,'Ankit','Ankit'),('Jalfaizy',22,'Jalfaizy',"aa"),('saurabh',20,'saurabh',"bb"),('Bala',26,"aa","bb")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1]),lname=x[2],mname=x[3]))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
schemaPeople.show()
```

after executing above code my result is like below.

```
+---+--------+-----+--------+
|age|   lname|mname|    name|
+---+--------+-----+--------+
| 25|   Ankit|Ankit|   Ankit|
| 22|Jalfaizy|   aa|Jalfaizy|
| 20| saurabh|   bb| saurabh|
| 26|      aa|   bb|    Bala|
+---+--------+-----+--------+
```

but I want map each column value in the each row and based on age column what are the columns are same , my expected result is like below.

```
+---+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|age| lname_map_same | mname_map_same    |    name_map_same |
+---+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 25|  mname,name    |   lname,name      |   lname,mname    |
| 22|    name        |  none             |   lname          |
| 20|    name        |  none             |   lname          |
| 26|    none        |  none             |   none           |
+---+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Respected output looks quite suspicious to me. Are you sure this is what should be the output?

Comment: yes ,what ever output I mentioned in my question is correct,for easy understanding which are the columns are equal in the give row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem with a map function. Have a look at the following code:

```py
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
( 25,"Ankit","Ankit","Ankit"),( 22,"Jalfaizy","aa","Jalfaizy"),( 26,"aa","bb","Bala")
], ("age", "lname","mname","name"))
#only 3 records added to dataset

def find_identical(row):
    labels = ["lname","mname","name"]
    result = [row[0],]                 #save the age for final result
    row = row[1:]                      #drop the age from row
    for i in range(3):
        s = []
        field = row[i]
        if field == row[(i+1)%3]:     #check whether field is identical with next field
            s.append(labels[(i+1)%3])
        if field == row[(i-1)%3]:     #check whether field is identical with previous field
            s.append(labels[(i-1)%3])
        if not s:                     #if no identical values found return None
            s = None     
        result.append(s)
    return result

df_new.rdd.map(find_identical).toDF(["age","lname_map_same","mname_map_same","name_map_same"]).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|age|lname_map_same|mname_map_same| name_map_same|
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 25| [mname, name]| [name, lname]|[lname, mname]|
| 22|        [name]|          null|       [lname]|
| 26|          null|          null|          null|
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

If you want to have 5 columns that should be considered, you can follow the instructions in the comment. So you have to modify the labels list and add an additional if statement. Furthermore, all modulo operations have to be adjusted to match with 5 and the for-loop should iterate over 5 elements. Then you end up with the code looking like:

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
( 25,"Ankit","Ankit","Ankit","Ankit","Ankit"),( 22,"Jalfaizy","aa","Jalfaizy","Jalfaizy","aa"),( 26,"aa","bb","Bala","cc","dd")
], ("age", "lname","mname","name","n1","n2"))

def find_identical(row):
    labels = ["lname","mname","name","n1","n2"]
    result = [row[0],]
    row = row[1:]
        for i in range(5):
            s = []
            field = row[i]
            if field == row[(i+1)%5]:
                s.append(labels[(i+1)%5])
            if field == row[(i-1)%5]:
                s.append(labels[(i-1)%5])
            if field == row[(i+2)%5]:
                s.append(labels[(i+2)%5])
            if field == row[(i+3)%5]:
                s.append(labels[(i+3)%5])
            if not s:
                s = None
            result.append(s)
        return result

df_new.rdd.map(find_identical).toDF(["age","lname_map_same","mname_map_same","name_map_same","n1_map_same","n2_map_same"]).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
    +---+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|age|lname_map_same       |mname_map_same       |name_map_same         |n1_map_same             |n2_map_same             |
+---+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|25 |[mname, n2, name, n1]|[name, lname, n1, n2]|[n1, mname, n2, lname]|[n2, name, lname, mname]|[lname, n1, mname, name]|
|22 |[name, n1]           |[n2]                 |[n1, lname]           |[name, lname]           |[mname]                 |
|26 |null                 |null                 |null                  |null                    |null                    |
+---+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

The dynamic approach takes the number of columns as a parameter. But in my case the number should be between 1 and 5 since the dataset was created with maximum of 5 attributes. IT could look like this:

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
( 25,"Ankit","Ankit","Ankit","Ankit","Ankit"),( 22,"Jalfaizy","aa","Jalfaizy","Jalfaizy","aa"),( 26,"aa","bb","Bala","cc","dd")
], ("age", "n1","n2","n3","n4","n5"))


def find_identical(row,number):
    labels = []
    for n in range(1,number+1):
        labels.append("n"+str(n))   #create labels dynamically
    result = [row[0],]
    row = row[1:]
    for i in range(number):
        s = []
        field = row[i]
        for x in range(1,number):
            if field == row[(i+x)%number]:
                s.append(labels[(i+x)%number]) #check for similarity in all the other fields
        if not s:
            s = None
        result.append(s)
    return result

number=4
colNames=["age",]
for x in range(1,number+1):
    colNames.append("n"+str(x)+"_same") #create the 'nX_same' column names
df_new.rdd.map(lambda r: find_identical(r,number)).toDF(colNames).show(truncate=False)
```

Depending on the number parameter the output varies, and I kept the age column statically as the first column.

Output:

```
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|age|n1_same     |n2_same     |n3_same     |n4_same     |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|25 |[n2, n3, n4]|[n3, n4, n1]|[n4, n1, n2]|[n1, n2, n3]|
|22 |[n3, n4]    |null        |[n4, n1]    |[n1, n3]    |
|26 |null        |null        |null        |null        |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi gaw, thanks for quick reply now it is hard coded in to 3 value but if it 4 columns it is not working as expected,can you please help me on this.

Comment: If it is 4 columns (so age + 4 additional columns) you have to add another label in the labels array and replace `range(3)` with `range(4)` and all modulo operators (e.g. all `%3` with `%4`) and it should work. and you have to add an additional if statement: `if field == row[(i+2)%4]:
            s.append(labels[(i+2)%4])`

Comment: i have add following code " labels = ["lname","mname","name","n1","n2"]
    result = [row[0],]                 #save the age for final result
    row = row[1:]                      #drop the age from row
    for i in range(5): " but not working

Comment: it is giving wrong result like  [mname, n2] instead of 5 matching columns headers.

Comment: thanks for update,this will work for only 5 columns right.because we are hard coding range values.can please suggest  dynamically  instead of hard coded  values.

Comment: a dynamic version still needs a set of labels, but i can assume that you simply enumerate the labels? then the labels for the columns could be something like n1, n2, .... I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks Gaw, I have changed  number hard coded  to "labels= [col_name for col_name in df_new.columns]
number=len(labels)-2", is i

Comment: Thanks alot in Advance :)

Comment: Your welcome. Why you reduce the columns by 2?  I thought only age should be discarded. Anyway, I hope now everything will work fine

Comment: Hi gaw.can you please suggest now labels are n1,n2,n3 but it should be exact label name.please help me on this.

Comment: If you have the label names in the array `labels` you can pass it to the function. 
Change `.map(lambda r: find_identical(r,number))` to `.map(lambda r: find_identical(r,number,labels))` and modify the function to `def find_identical(row,number, labels):` and comment out or remove the definition of the labels array in the function